# Create a dynamically button for each table row using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, oop, javascript-objects

so Im having a little bit of trouble, what I want to do is when i press the edit progress buton, to be able to change the onPage value. But with this code I currently have when i press on the button i only get printed the Id from the last button in the row. The others dont work.

````
let counter = 0;

  const populateTable = (title, author, maxPages, onPage) => {  
  counter++;
  tBody.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${title}</td><td>${author}</td><td>${maxPages}</td><td>${onPage}</td><td     style="width: 100px; padding:0;">${readPercentage(
     onPage,
    maxPages
  )}</td><td>
  <button id="edit-${counter}" class="editBtn">
    Edit Progress
  </button>`your text`
</td></tr>`;
  let editBtn = document.querySelector(`#edit-${counter}`);
  editBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => ``your text``{
    editProgress(event.target.id);
  });
let editProgress = (editId) => {
  let index = editId.split("-")[1];
  console.log(index);
};`your text```your text``
`your text`
books.forEach((el, key) =>
  populateTable(el.title, el.author, el.maxPages, el.onPage, key)
);

};
````

When i trigger the addEvent listener on the first four buttons i dont get nothing printed in the console, on the last row when i click i get the <button id="edit-${counter}" as 5, because i have 5 objects in the array, when i add 6th object dynamicly, my edit button only prints for the sixth row and only 6 in the console log. How can i fix this problem ? Thanks :D

Comment: Try and add a working snippet to the question.

Comment: Unable to investigate because of syntax errors caused by random insertions of `your text` into the code. Please remove them and share code that produces the behavior described. This will greatly increase our ability to provide assistance.